# Does doxygen support templates for the HTML output?

Tags: documentation, templates, documentation-generation

I've documented my code for `doxygen`, but I don't want the default HTML it gives. I know I can customize it by providing custom CSS, headers, footers, etc. (like GNOME does), and how I can add common PHP code to the files and tell it to save as `.php`, but that isn't really what I want.

What I want is output like MSDN. I can't describe it really. My question is, Is this possible using doxygen with something like templates, or do I have to output XML and parse it with another program (that I wouldn't mind writing)?

Comment: Might look into this: MSDN integration
For those using Windows and wanting to integrate the compressed HTML generated by doxygen into MSDN look at this MSDN integrator utility. http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/helpers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doxygen does not support something like *HTML templates* out of the box, as far as I know. You can refer to the image below (from the [official doxygen homepage](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html)). It shows the input and output files that are related into the entire documentation creation workflow.

[image]

As you can see, doxygen reads a so called "Layout file". This file [can be customized](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html)! However you are somehow restricted to the page structure, doxygen creates.

If you need more flexibility you should prefer [to XSLT transform XML output](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html). There is also an [sample](http://www.doxygen.org/dl/xslt-example.tgz) that shows you how to do this.